# Failed to install last NodeJs version on Debian 9

Tags: node.js, linux, debian

I tried to install NodeJS on my Debian 9 by following the steps on [NodeJs website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)

When I do :

```
sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
```

I get an error that I think has no relation to Node:

> E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease

(I don't know if this could impact Node's installation or not)

After that I did :

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

The program finished the installation, but it installed v4.8.2 and not the last version.

And when I do :

```
nodejs -v
```

I get :

```
v4.8.2
```

I tried to add those two lines to my nodesource.list file:

```
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_9.x stretch main 
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_9.x stretch main
```

And then `apt-get update` but this did not resolve the issue.

What should I do?

**EDIT**: When I do `apt update` I get an error too (Maybe I didn't notice it before), and I think this was the cause of the issue.
This error is

> Err:1 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable InRelease

I found a solution for this [here](https://github.com/SynoCommunity/spksrc/issues/2367). I fixed that and I successfully installed the last version of NodeJS after that.

Answer (score 1):

After trying different things i figured out that i'am getting an error when i do `apt update`
The error is : Err:1 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable InRelease.
So this is the real problem.
I found a solution for this error in [github](https://github.com/SynoCommunity/spksrc/issues/2367)
(its an internet configuration problem).
I fixed that and i succeed to install the last version of Node.Js after that.